# "Aquele email que respondi a pouco" ou "aquele email que respondi há pouco"? Qual a forma correta?

Tags: gramática, ortografia, diferenças

"Aquele email que respondi a pouco" ou "aquele email que respondi há pouco"? Qual a forma correta de escrever a frase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Há" é o presente do indicativo do verbo "haver", e "haver é sinônimo de "ter" na linguagem coloquial. Veja que "Aquele e-mail que respondi **tem** pouco" faz sentido (embora você possa não gostar do estilo demasiado informal).

Quando é o caso de usar "a" ?

Em quatro casos:

1. O nome da letra "a", ou quando é usado para substituir algo desconhecido ou que não se quer definir: "O **a** é a primeira letra do alfabeto", "Nesse caso, **a** é o dobro de b", "O deputado **a** votou contra a proposta do deputado b".
2. Quando é sinônimo de "primeiro" ou de "dez": "O item **A**", "Tirei **A** na prova".
3. Quando é artigo feminino singular: "Onde está **a** carta que escrevi há pouco?" Veja que aqui a substituição por "ter" é impraticável:

*"Onde está **tem** carta que escrevi há pouco?"

Como é artigo, flexiona em gênero: "Onde está **o** e-mail que escrevi há pouco?", então é fácil de verificar se a gente substituir o substantivo por um substantivo mascuino.

4. Quando é preposição: "Onde está o e-mail que tenho de mandar daqui **a** meia-hora?". Veja que aqui de novo "tem" não pode ser usado:

*"Onde está o e-mail que tenho de mandar daqui **tem** meia-hora?"

E nem mudar o gênero do substantivo faz com que esse "a" vire "o":

*"Onde está o e-mail que tenho de mandar daqui **o** meio-minuto?"

E, finalmente, existe o temido "à", que é uma contração dos dois casos anteriores, preposição e artigo:

"Onde está o e-mail que tenho de mandar **à** procuradora-geral do município?"

Veja que aqui a substituição por tem é de novo impossível:

*"Onde está o e-mail que tenho de mandar **tem** procuradora-geral do município?"

Mas como há um artigo envolvido, mudar o gênero do substantivo faz sentido, mas tem efeito sobre a palavra:

"Onde está o e-mail que tenho de mandar **ao** procurador-geral do município?"

Por outro lado, a preposição "a" é um sinônimo aproximado da preposição "para" - e por isso "à" deve ser empregado quando é possível a substituição por "para a":

"Onde está o e-mail que tenho de mandar **para a** procuradora-geral do município?"

E, finalmente, a preposição "a" é um antônimo aproximado da preposição "de", de modo que nos casos em que há movimento implicado, o movimento contrário resulta em "de" quando a gente deve usar "a", e em "da" (preposição mais artigo), quando a gente deve usar "à":

"Onde está o e-mail que tenho de enviar **a** São Paulo?"

"Onde está o e-mail que recebi **de** São Paulo?"

Mas

"Onde está o e-mail que tenho de enviar **à** Paraíba?"

"Onde está o e-mail que recebi **da** Paraíba?"

Answer (score 0):

O correto é utilizar "há pouco".

A diferença entre **há** e **a** é bastante confundida pelos brasileiros, no entanto, é bem simples de entender.

> Não quero comer, obrigado. Comi muito bolo há pouco tempo.

e

> Estou muito ansioso, pois eu estou a 9 horas de conhecer o amor da minha vida.

Como você pode notar, no primeiro exemplo, o **há** é utilizado com sentido de passado e, além disso, ele pode ser substituído pelo verbo "faz" de modo que continue fazendo sentido. Já no segundo exemplo, o **a** é utilizado com sentido de futuro.

Caso queira ler um pouco mais sobre o assunto, sinta-se livre para verificar este [manual de redação](https://www.estadao.com.br/manualredacao/erro) do jornal brasileiro Estadão. A explicação acerca da sua questão encontra-se no 51° tópico.

Comment: «A diferença entre há e a é bastante confundida pelos seres humanos fluentes na lingua portuguesa» Em Portugal não, porque têm pronúncias diferentes. "Há" tem som aberto, como "paz", e "a" tem som fechado, como o a final de "maçã" mas sem anasalar.

Comment: Muito interessante saber isso, ANeves. Obrigado. Já imaginava que havia uma diferença entre a pronúncia, mas não sabia que era bem diferenciável para os portugueses, já que, além da pronúncia, a escrita e o significado também são um tanto semelhantes e isso pode confundir muitos.

Comment: Sim. Cá "há" e "à" são homófonas, e às vezes são usadas erradamente. Mas "a" não.